# jQuery first hover issue?

Tags: jquery, css, web, overflow, delay

I have a question that probably will have a simple answer, but I can't seem to figure it out.

On my website, I have a navigation bar that when hover over, flips using CSS/jQuery. I have a dropdown on the second nav item, which works, and shows the dropdown when hovered over... I added code in case the item was hovered over then back off quickly that the dropdown didn't mess up. It works, but not on the first time (e.g. Hover, quickly off = doesn't work... Hover, quickly off again = does work). It is viewable [here.](http://theknockitoff.com/test/loggedin/)

You can view source to see the HTML (it's not too cluttered at the moment without any content). The jQuery looks like this:

```
$("#navigation ul .dropdown").hover(
    function(){
        if(windowWidth > 730){
            //in case not faded out already
            $(this).find("ul").fadeOut(10);

            $(this).delay(600).queue(function(){
                $(this).find("ul").fadeIn("slow");
                $(this).removeClass("hideOver");

                $("#navigation ul .dropdown").mouseleave(function(){
                    $(this).addClass("hideOver");
                    $(this).dequeue();
                });

                $(this).dequeue();
            }); //end queue

            $("#navigation ul .dropdown").mouseleave(function(){
                $(this).addClass("hideOver");
            });

        } //end if (for web view only)
    }, function(){
        $(this).addClass("hideOver");
    }
);
```

The CSS classes are: hideOver (overflow: hidden), and showOver (overflow: visible).

When it messes up the first time, it looks like this (because the class isn't being applied for some reason):

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you set up the relevant bits of code in a fiddle? Your site may change or go down in the future and wouldn't be as much help to future users with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Does changing the code from:

```
$("#navigation ul .dropdown").hover
```

to:

```
$("#navigation ul .dropdown").mouseenter
```

solve the issue? The hover is triggered whenever a mouseenters or leaves an area. So if you already have a mouseleave event, maybe what you are looking for is a mouseenter event?

Comment: I've tried that... If I do mouseenter, it doesn't do the dropdown for some reason.